# ACF if field one available show field one otherwise wordpress title

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I need if else statement with the following values using ACF Plugin.

I have a field named "headline":

```
<?php if ( get_field( 'headline') ) { ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark">
        <img src="<?php the_field( 'headline' ); ?>" />
    </a>
<?php } ?>
```

Wordpress Title Code:

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink()); ?>">
     <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(), $thumbnail_size , array('alt' => get_the_title(),'title' => ''));  ?>
</a>
```

What I want: If field one headline is available then show field one otherwise show the second code of wordpress title

Comment: `headline` stores the title or the image src?

Comment: SO is not a free coding service. Please add some code you’ve already tried in order to get help about why it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php $headline = get_field( 'headline'); ?>
<?php if($headline) { ?>
     <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark">
         <img src="<?php the_field( 'headline' ); ?>" />
     </a>
<?php } else { ?>
     <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink()); ?>">
         <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(), $thumbnail_size , array('alt' => get_the_title(),'title' => ''));  ?>
     </a>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<?php if(!empty(get_field( 'headline'))) { ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark">
    <img src="<?php the_field( 'headline' ); ?>" />

<?php } else { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink()); ?>">
    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(), $thumbnail_size , array('alt' => get_the_title(),'title' => ''));  ?></a>

<?php } ?>
```